# Extract keys from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column named Notes_Key where the vendor has stuck three keys (with whitespace padding) into that column.  I am on MS SQL2012

Example Data

```
THOBUI         R4044     004
```

I access out each value so I can access these

```
THOBUI
R4044
004
```

Update - I actually need the data this way

| VendorCode | JobCode | OrderCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| THOBUI | R4044 | 004 |

This way I can join to other tables.  And there shouldn't be more records than these 3.

**NOTE:**

Arbitrary code from a comment below...

```
SELECT 
    Members.Member.value('.','VARCHAR(8000)') Keys 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        CAST('<Notes_Type><PA_NOTES_MC>' 
        + REPLACE(Notes_Key, ' ' , '</PA_NOTES_MC><PA_NOTES_MC>') 
        + '</PA_NOTES_MC></Notes_Type>' AS XML) AS tempCRN 
    FROM 
        PA_NOTES_MC 
    WHERE 
        Company_Code = 'REC' AND 
        Notes_Key LIKE '%R4044%' ) AS tempCRN 
    CROSS APPLY 
    tempCRN.nodes('/Notes_Type/PA_NOTES_MC') Members(Member)) 

SELECT 
    Keys, 
    'Name' AS KeyName 
FROM 
    tmp 
WHERE 
    Keys !=''
```

Comment: So are you wanting to extract each value from the string? What have you tried so far?  Do the widths vary?  [Does this help](https://datatofish.com/left-right-substring-sql-server/)?

Comment: It appears to be fixed width columns of 6 chars per "key" (the second one being missing in your example). Is that the case?

Comment: I left tried combinations of right/left, charindex-len.  I have gotten first value with a LEFT(Notes_Key, CHARINDEX(' ', Notes_Key)) AS Vendor but not the other two.  The padding isn't consistent per key.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  How does "004" become "0004"?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please do **not** put code in comments. If you found a solution, add an answer. If it's additional information **[edit]** your question.

Comment: I think I got it by using this 
```
SELECT Members.Member.value('.','VARCHAR(8000)') Keys FROM (  
SELECT CAST('<Notes_Type><PA_NOTES_MC>'         
+ REPLACE(Notes_Key, ' ' , '</PA_NOTES_MC><PA_NOTES_MC>')      
+ '</PA_NOTES_MC></Notes_Type>' AS XML) AS tempCRN   
FROM PA_NOTES_MC where Company_Code = 'REC' and Notes_Key LIKE '%R4044%' ) AS tempCRN  
CROSS APPLY tempCRN.nodes('/Notes_Type/PA_NOTES_MC') Members(Member)  )    SELECT Keys, 'Name' AS KeyName FROM tmp WHERE Keys !='' 

Now I need to PIVOT out the data

Answer (score 0):

The use of `charindex()` suggests that you are using SQL Server.  If so, you can use `string_split()` in the more recent versions:

```
select e.*, s.valu
from example e cross apply
     string_split(e.col, ' ') s
where s.value <> '';
```

Comment: We are on SQL2012 so I don't think it's available.